# Как начать пользоваться postgresql в visual studio 2019 c использованием qt

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, postgresql, visual-studio-2019

Установил postgresql и проверил подключение к базе данных через pgAdmin4.exe. Имеется проект в Visual studio c подключенным qt. Вопрос в том, как начать в этом проекте пользоваться postgresql? Как подсоединиться к серверу и начать передавать запросы и получать ответы с сервера

**upd**: драйвер QPSQL not loaded. Не пойму как загрузить

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-programming.html

Comment: @e.n.shirokov ?

Answer (score 0):

В документации к Qt [указано следующее](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql):

> Предупреждение: если вы собираете подключаемый модуль QPSQL с PostgreSQL версии 9.2 или новее, вы должны распространять свое приложение с libpq версии 9.2 или новее. В противном случае загрузка плагина QPSQL завершится ошибкой со следующим сообщением:

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QMARIADB QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
Could not create database object
```

Вам нужно рядом с приложением положить библиотеку libpq, либо указать путь к каталогу, её содержащему, в PATH при запуске.